# Is there a way to extract & store garlic oil, without being infused with any other oil, such as olive?

Tags: storage-method, oil, food-preservation, garlic

Have attempted to find ways to extract & preserve straight garlic oil. Only info I have found, have "added" oils, such as olive. I just want to know if it is safe to extract the oil from garlic, with a press maybe? And, of course, best way to store for long term use, if possible?
Thanx for your time!
N.Stark

Comment: @Luciano Aw, I'd *just* finished writing an answer.

Comment: @Sneftel maybe we close this one and you add your answer on the other Q...

Comment: @Luciano Nah, both of the existing answers are better than mine :)